# Profile incorrectly shows Reputation by the week

Tags: support, bug, reputation, profile-page, reputation-leagues

I've noticed in the last few days that if you go to someones Profile Page that there reputation shows *top 3% this week* or whatever the percent is.  However, sometimes that % isn't for the week.  If you reload the page for that user then it says the correct time-period of month, quarter, year, all-time, whatever.

I tested it with my own [profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2145211/harrison) and others like [martijn-pieters](https://stackoverflow.com/users/100297/martijn-pieters).  I didn't have many points for the week whatsoever, and then it changed back to quarter like it should have (or year for Martijn) when the page is reloaded.

Has anyone else noticed this?  Is this a bug with SO?

As requested here are some screen shots.  This doesn't happen with every user or every time.  I noticed this last time that the Reputation was calculating when it occurred.

If it matters I was using Google Chrome.

[image: Shows Week Reputation on first load]

[image: Shows Month Reputation on reload]

You can also see it should be month not week based on league rankings.

**Week Rank**

> ```
> [abarnert]
> abarnert
> 3 32 77
> member for: 2 years, 2 months
> **#747 week rank**
> -716 change
> 65,016 total reputation
> 155 week reputation
> ```

**Month Rank**

> ```
> [abarnert]
> abarnert
> 3 32 77
> member for: 2 years, 2 months
> **#19 month rank**
> +46 change
> 65,016 total reputation
> 6,408 month reputation
> ```

Here it is for me and I'm definitely not in the top 3% for the week.

> ```
> Harrison
> 2 16 
> member for: 7 months link
> #7296 week rank 
> -5786 change 
> 906 total reputation 
> 25 week reputation
> ```

[image: My Profile Page showing week instead of quarter]

Comment: Hmm... I just viewed the two profiles you linked, and I saw year and quarter.

Comment: @AndrewBarber Wierd.  Once I load the page again it says it right, because it is in cache, but I know you wouldn't have had my profile in cache, so I don't get it.

Comment: @Harrison Oh, umm... yes, not in cache, because I'm not stalking you ;)

Comment: @Dukeling.  I have updated adding screenshots.  It took about 7 or 8 users to find one that showed the issue, but there you go.

Comment: Probably my fault. I'll take a look.

Comment: @Sklivvz It's always Sklivvz.

Comment: According to http://jsfiddle.net/AYPpF/82/embedded/result/ it was balpha's fault.

Comment: @AndrewBarber *wrong* it's always caching, and I'm almost certain it *is* caching this time. Checking with Marc Gravell... :-)

Comment: @Sklivvz Did you change something?  Now it's acting a little different.  Now it will sometimes not show the top % at all instead of showing it for week and then at reload shows it properly.

Comment: There was a caching issue due to some change, now the cache has been invalidated. It's a long running query.